# PYTHONPATH not being updated

Tags: python, vim, emacs

Currently I use `pyenv` to have a particular `python` version installed.  Then I use `pipenv` to create virtual environments for my various projects in `python`.

Currently I have a project structure similar to:

```
foo/
  src/app.py
  src/__init__.py
  tests/unit/test_app.py
  tests/unit/__init_.py
```

There are any given number of tests in `test_app.py` that import the `app.py` as:

```py
import src.app
```

I have two issues:

- Code editors like `emacs`, `vim` or `vscode` do complain about that `import` clause from the tests, marking it in red and being "moderately" annoying.
- From the text editors I invoke `pipenv run pytest` to check the tests.  It fails because `src` is not a module that it can find.  If I invoke the same command from my terminal in the project directory I get the same error.

If I invoke it as a `python` module like `pipenv run python -m pytest` it does work, since it adds the current directory to `PYTHONPATH`.  If I start the editors from a `pipenv shell` the tests also work.
Regardless how I start the editors the `import src.app` is marked as not valid.

If I start the editor setting `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:.` the tests also work, yet the syntax check still complains.

What is the cleanest way of handling this with editors like `emacs` or `vim`?  I would not like to move to `pycharm` and similar tools that "automatically" solve this issue.

Comment: Vim has no built-in mechanism for checking Python syntax, so whatever complains about syntax is not Vim itself.  Also Vim is not a shell, so unless you do special arrangements there is little reason for you to expect `pyenv` and `pipenv` to get inherited by whatever plugin(s) your Vim uses to check Python syntax.  What those arrangements might be depends on said plugin(s).  If you aren't willing to take the time to understand how your toolchain works then `pycharm` really is a better solution for you.

Comment: I am familiar with `vim` plugins and `emacs` layers.

In this particular case my `pipenv` is loaded into my `python` layer in `emacs` and it is shown in the interface, yet it is unable to update the `PYTHONPATH` to add the directory where the project is, hence considering all the internal dependencies (like unit tests) broken since it cannot find the packages.

Comment: What are you using for syntax checking in Vim?  If it's something that runs linters with Vim's `%!` or with `system()` then your problem is the linters run in a new shell, and you need to make sure `pyenv` is run in this new shell before the linters.  If it's something that uses Vim's internal interpreter then you (obviously) can't change Python's version, and you need to make sure said interpreter is aware of the relevant `$PYTHONPATH` before the interpreter runs the lints.  I know nothing about `emacs`.

Answer (score 0):

According to `pipenv` documentation; Any `.env` file in the directory where `pipenv` is invoked from is loaded.

This means that (for example) when you have `test_app.py` open in `emacs` while using the `python` layer, the `pipenv` of the project is loaded (as usual) but the `.env` is also automatically loaded and the internal dependencies of the file will work.

So for example, creating `.env` with this content at the project's root works for me:

```bsh
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:.
```

Now, you will be able also to run unit tests directly from `emacs` without facing problems with the imports.

This is the only way I was able to make it work, yet the solution feels hack-ish and inelegant.